# How to substitute with Comma Separate values in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a scenario like below (Oracle's SQL).

Table:`Employee`

| S.No | Name | Role |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | ELE,PLU,OTH |
| 2 | b | MAN,DIR |
| 3 | c | DIR,FND |
| 4 | d |  |

Table: `Role_master`

| Role | Role name |
| --- | --- |
| ELE | Electrician |
| PLU | Plumber |
| MAN | Manager |
| DIR | Director |
| FND | Founder |
| OTH | Other |

With the above tables, i would like to join both and expecting the output like below. Please help on the better way.

| S.No | Name | Role |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | Electrician,Plumber,Other |
| 2 | b | Manager,Director |
| 3 | c | Director,Founder |
| 4 | d |  |

Comment: Having a comma-delimited list of values in a single column (your ROLE column of EMPLOYEE table) violates the _very first_ rule of data design.    If an employee can have multiple roles, then there should be a second table, say EMP_ROLES, with one row per employee/role combination, and a FK back to the EMPLOYEE TABLE.  Proper data design makes problems like this become trivial, if not make them disappear completely.  You should spend some time studying DATA NORMALIZATION.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option:

- sample data in lines #1 - 12; query begins at line #14
- split `employee.role` into rows (i.e. separate values) so that you could **join** them to `role_master.role`
- aggregate them back (using `listagg`)

---

```
SQL> with
  2  employee (sno, name, role) as
  3    (select 1, 'a', 'ELE,PLU,OTH' from dual union all
  4     select 2, 'b', 'MAN,DIR'     from dual
  5    ),
  6  role_master (role, role_name) as
  7    (select 'ELE', 'Electrician' from dual union all
  8     select 'PLU', 'Plumber'     from dual union all
  9     select 'OTH', 'Other'       from dual union all
 10     select 'MAN', 'Manager'     from dual union all
 11     select 'DIR', 'Director'    from dual
 12    )
 13  --
 14  select e.sno,
 15         e.name,
 16         listagg(m.role_name, ',') within group (order by column_value) role
 17  from employee e cross join
 18    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 19                        connect by level <= regexp_count(e.role, ',') + 1
 20                       ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 21    join role_master m on m.role = regexp_substr(e.role, '[^,]+', 1, column_value)
 22  group by e.sno, e.name;

       SNO NAME ROLE
---------- ---- ----------------------------------------
         1 a    Electrician,Plumber,Other
         2 b    Manager,Director

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could use this logic :

1. First, generate the maximum number of rows needed for the split step (required_rows_v)
2. Then, make left join between the three data sources like below
3. Then, use listagg function to re-aggregate rows

```sql
With required_rows_v (lvl) as (
select level lvl
from dual
connect by level <= ( select max( regexp_count( e.Role, '[^,]+' )  )  from employee e )
)
select e.SNO,
      e.NAME,
    listagg(rm.Role_name, ',')within group (order by e.SNo, v.lvl) Role
from employee e
left join required_rows_v v on v.lvl <= regexp_count( e.Role, '[^,]+' )
left join Role_master rm on rm.Role = regexp_substr( e.Role, '[^,]+', 1, v.lvl )
group by e.SNO, e.NAME
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=78b2067ae026a18d98e03a0420826a9a)